# Цикл для обработки файлов в атачменты к письму

Tags: php

Не могу найти цикл, который бы принимал фотографии сохранял их на сервер, и передавал в виде атачмента в письмо.

Сам написал такой вариант, но он не атачит как надо. Приходит только гигантский код который составляет картинку

```
foreach($_FILES as $fields) {
    foreach($fields['name'] as $index => $file_name) {
        $files[$file_name] = array(
        'type' => $fields['type'][$index],
        'num' => $index,
        'tmp_name' => $fields['tmp_name'][$index]);
    }
}
//удаляем пустые элементы массива
foreach($files as $key=>$value) {
    if ($key=='') {
        unset($files[$key]);
    }
}

//перекидываем в img файлы
foreach($files as $key=>$value) {
    $temp_path = './img/'.$key;
    move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], $temp_path);
}

foreach($files as $key=>$value) {
$filename = './img/'.$key;
$f = $value['num'];
$f = fopen($filename,"rb");
$zag .="Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"".basename($filename)."\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"".basename($filename)."\"\r\n"
."\r\n";
$zag .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($f,filesize($filename))))."\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как минимум нужно поменять content-type на что-то из этого: [Список MIME-типов, image](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2#image)

Edit: Видимо с первого раза было непонятно. Если вы ожидаете увидеть картинку, то content-type должен быть соответственным, в википедии по указанной выше ссылке есть специальный раздел с типами для изображений:

> image/gif 
>       image/jpeg
>       image/pjpeg
>       image/png
>       image/svg+xml
>       image/tiff
>       image/vnd.microsoft.icon
>       image/vnd.wap.wbmp

Comment: все равно шлет  в таком формате
http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/3f5a5-clip-238kb.png

Comment: В вашем скрине видно что content-type все еще не верный для изображения

Comment: А почему на картинке заголовки части письма вытянуты в одну строчку? Не потому ли, что разделитель заголовков - `\r\n`, а не `\n`?

Comment: обновил с код с вашими правками, все равно картинку присылает в тексте.

Comment: Без полного исходника (для начала только письма) мы гадать можем до бесконечности.